# Why is my calculation total not updating correctly in Acrobat?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, arraylist, acrobat

I am working on an order form in Acrobat that calculates sales tax for whichever state is selected in a drop down. If I enter in one item, it is not adding the tax to the total. And if I go back and change the state, it updates the sales tax correctly, but the total includes the previous sales tax, not the current.

I am receiving this error:

```
InvalidSetError: Set not possible, invalid or unknown.
Field.value:8:Field TOTAL AMOUNT:Calculate
```

Here is my calculation for the total:

```
var a=this.getField("Subtotal without customization charges");
var b=this.getField("Customization Charges");
var c=this.getField("Tax3");
var d=this.getField("Shipping");
var e=this.getField("Express Handling");
var f=this.getField("Discount Total");
var g=this.getField("TOTAL AMOUNT");
g.value=(a.value+b.value+c.value+d.value+e.value)-(f.value);
```

"State" field dropdown:

```
if(event.target.value!="State")
{
this.getField("Sales Tax").value=event.target.value;
}
```

"Sales Tax" field is hidden and shows the export value of whatever is selected in the "State" field.

"Tax" field is hidden and is the product of "Customization Charges" x "Subtotal without customization charges"

"Tax2" field is hidden and has this calculation:

```
var a=this.getField("Tax");
var b=this.getField("Discount Total");
var c=this.getField("Tax2");
c.value=(a.value)-(b.value);
```

"Tax3" field is visible and is the product of "Sales Tax" x "Tax2"

Comment: Where exactly did you put this JavaScript? What field and what Action?

Comment: @joelgeraci I put the JavaScript in the custom calculation script section under the "Calculate" tab of the properties panel of the "TOTAL AMOUNT" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Instead of creating four fields to calculate tax, I consolidated it into two. I think it was not reading the equation in the proper order because the chain of calculations was spread out between four fields.

One hidden field which is the export value of the drop down.
One visible field "Sales Tax" calculation:

```
var a=this.getField("Subtotal without customization charges");
var b=this.getField("Customization Charges");
var c=this.getField("Discount Total");
var d=this.getField("Tax Calculation");
event.value=((a.value+b.value)-(c.value))*(d.value);
```

"TOTAL AMOUNT" field calculation:

```
var a=this.getField("Subtotal without customization charges");
var b=this.getField("Customization Charges");
var c=this.getField("Sales Tax");
var d=this.getField("Shipping");
var e=this.getField("Express Handling");
var f=this.getField("Discount Total");
event.value=((a.value+b.value+c.value)-(f.value))+(d.value+e.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running your code during the calculation event, you can't set the value of the field... because that's what the calculation is trying to do. That's what is producing the error. In the last line of your code, you are trying to set the value of the field, you need to set the value of the calculation event instead. So the code looks like this...

```
var a=this.getField("Subtotal without customization charges");
var b=this.getField("Customization Charges");
var c=this.getField("Tax3");
var d=this.getField("Shipping");
var e=this.getField("Express Handling");
var f=this.getField("Discount Total");
event.value=(a.value+b.value+c.value+d.value+e.value)-(f.value);
```

Also, change the propery of the tax dropdown to "Commit selected value immediately" in the options tab.